# Reason for using 4-spaces instead of 2-spaces?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Is there any rationale why HapiJS endorses using 4-space indentations?

Source: http://hapijs.com/styleguide

Comment: It's what they prefer?

Comment: Haha, yes I do realize that. It's a "style." I'm just wondering if there's a reason beyond that, e.g. discourages callback hell or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** No better reason than anyone else - styleguides are typically only rules for project maintainers. They had to adopt some convention and that was the choice. As a user, you don't really need to care.

**Long answer:** Hapi is a great framework, built by the folks at Walmart. and specifically a person named Eran Hammer who was unhappy about some architectural choices made by [Express](https://github.com/strongloop/express), another server framework for [Node](https://nodejs.org/). It is somewhat opinionated in general, it was effectively created in an environment of opinion, not to mention a large company (which means it desperately needed a convention). That said, you can safely use the Hapi API with any indentation you want, including tabs, though. Likewise, the Hapi internals could have been written the same way. Their specific choice likely comes down to established tools or conventions already in use at the company. Many different projects make [different choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070927/is-it-safe-to-indent-with-2-spaces) for a [variety of reasons](http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html). In my experience, many large JavaScript applications go with 2 spaces and the Node.js core itself is [written with 2](https://github.com/joyent/node). But there's nothing wrong with those that do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate the thought that went into it. I think I was looking for some kinda sage wisdom on 4-spaces. I'm a philosophical guy, and I never tire of hearing about peoples opinions on why they went one route or another.

Comment: Anytime, @wle :) this kind of question is important for beginners, too. A common thought process I hear is, "Well, if people are so opinionated about this topic, there must be some kind of logic behind it, right?" There is, even if it's not 100% definitive. It makes it easy to wonder if you are doing something wrong, unless we make it abundantly clear that most technologies can handle whatever you choose. It's an unusually human-oriented thing in the realm of telling a computer what to do.